# How can I insert column comments through a Standard SQL script?

Tags: sql, standards-compliance, ansi-sql

I want a script that inserts table comments and column comments. Said script must be unique and run satisfactorily both on Oracle and MySQL. Furthermore, I prefer it to be written in Standard SQL.

This is how I do it now. But it does not work on MySQL.

```
comment on table F_Transaction 
    is 'Fact table for system transactions';

comment on column F_Transaction.Transaction_Date
    is 'Date in which the transaction took place';
```

What SQL construction should I use to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Do you have a question, or would you like us to do your job for you?

Comment: Neville, I didn't ask anyone to come to my office at 8 am, nor to edit all the scripts, nor to do anything I already know how to do. I've just got blocked at this particular point and I'm asking for help. This is what Stack Overflow is for.
So, I want to do my job, I don't ask anyone to do it for me. I just have a question.

Comment: @Josep - I totally agree! Your question was simple enough to understand if someone had taken the time to bother reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [standards](http://savage.net.au/SQL/) do not seem to define any way to define table or column comments (looks like they don't even mention them). So, the syntax for comments on tables/columns can vary from one DBMS to another.

It seems that a number of DBMS agree with [Oracle's `COMMENT ON` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm) (see [Oracle create table with column comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10516284/851811)).

With MySQL it's necessary to specify the comments along with the table/column definition (in `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` sentences). See this related question: [Alter MYSQL Table To Add Comments on Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2162420/851811).